# Parameter of addEventListner

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yub2B/4/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

JS:

```
function test(x)
{
    alert(x);
}

var text=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0,l=text.length;i<l;i++)
{
    text[i].addEventListener("keydown",function()
    {
        test(i);
    },false);
}
```

And instead of outputing 0 for first textbox, 1 for second textbox ... it always ouput 4.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's infamous loop problem when assigning events inside loop. You are passing same value of `i` on each iteration, use this:

```
for(var i=0,l=text.length;i<l;i++)
{
   (function(i){
      text[i].addEventListener("keydown",function()
      {
         test(i);
      },false);

   })(i)
}
```

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yub2B/5/)